# Array being called as a sub or function incorrectly

Tags: function, excel, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors, vba

I am trying to store data in an array, but there is a `"Compile error: Sub or Function not defined"` thrown when I try to store the data.

I declared `CallsForecasted` before the sub in order to make it public as follows.

```
    Dim CallsForecasted(1 To 22, 1 To 6) As Double
```

This is the loop that I am getting the error on.

```
    For icount = 1 To 22
        For jcount = 1 To 6
            Select Case jcount
            Case 1
                CallsForecasted(icount, jcount) = MondayForecast * Worksheets("Erlang").Range("B" & (2 + icount))
            Case 2
               CallsForecasted(icount, jcount) = TuesdayForecast * Worksheets("Erlang").Range("C" & (2 + icount))
            Case 3
                CallsForecasted(icount, jcount) = WednesdayForecast * Worksheets("Erlang").Range("C" & (2 + icount))
            Case 4
                CallsForecasted(icount, jcount) = ThursdayForecast * Worksheets("Erlang").Range("C" & (2 + icount))
            Case 5
                CallsForecasted(icount, jcount) = FridayForecast * Worksheets("Erlang").Range("C" & (2 + icount))
            Case 6
                CallsForecasted(icount, jcount) = SaturdayForecast * Worksheets("Erlang").Range("D" & (2 + icount))
            End Select
        Next jcount
    Next icount
```

When the compiler error is thrown, the first instance of `"CallsForecasted(icount, jcount) ="` is highlighted (not the whole line, just that part).  Everything being stored in the array is a number.  I think that the compiler is trying to call the array as a sub or function.

I do have functions defined at the beginning of the code so that I can use an Erlang calculation, but they are all ended before I have anything else written.

Any ideas? this one has me totally stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move  `Dim CallsForecasted(1 To 22, 1 To 6) As Double` above any subroutines or functions.

I get a "Only Comments may appear after End Sub, End Function or End Property" compile error if I put the declaration lower in the procedure. Oddly, it still lets me run the procedure that calls `CallsForecasted` and then I don't get the compile error any more. But I do get the "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined" that your seeing.

So, it is confusing!

Comment: Thanks Doug! I'll give it a try. It's nice to know that I'm not the only one. :D

Comment: Yup, that did it!  Thanks Doug!  I figured that since I delcared it before the sub, it would work, but apparently it does have to be all the way at the top.  Thanks for helping me with a rookie error.